# C++ Template; Auto deduction return type of function passed as template argument;

Tags: c++, templates, decltype

I need to deduct a type of a return value of a getter function. That getter is passed as function pointer in template list.

So getter looks like:

```
using TGetter   = std::function<std::string(Me*)>;

std::string getter(Me* me)
{
    return std::string("string");
}
```

Template class

```
template<typename TGetter>
class Handler
{
public:
    Handler(TGetter getter)
        :m_getter(getter)
    {};

    using TValue =  std::string;  //decltype(TGetter()); <- something like that I want to get

private:
    TGetter                     m_getter;
    ...

    bool handler();
```

Instantiation is like that:

```
Handler<TGetter> h(getter);
```

What I want is to declare `TValue` depending on getter return type. 
So `std::string` as for getter in example. I'm gonna have different types of getters and wand to declare respective type simply like `TValue value;` inside a class.

`using TValue = decltype(TGetter());` is resolved into a function pointer.

Could you help me to get it right, thanks.

Comment: You are probably looking for `function::result_type`.

Comment: Is `TGetter` necessary a `std::function`? Do you know the expected parameters of `TGetter`?

Comment: @Jarod42 `TGetter` is a function pointer always, and parameter is known.

Comment: `std::function<std::string(Me*)>` is not a function pointer.

Comment: yes, you are right. Sorry, I'm not very well with that terminology. For now I think I would use only function as getters, not lambdas or other stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is [`result_type`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function), probably:

```
//...
public:
  using TValue =  typename TGetter::result_type;
//...
```

[Demo](https://www.ideone.com/BqGhPp).

Comment: For `std::function<>` that's seems to be the best solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Just use `std::declval` like that if your function has no arguments:

```
using TValue = decltype(std::declval<TGetter>()(/* your args go here */));
```

Comment: Getter takes a parameter. Is there a way to take function with a parameter?

Comment: Disadvantage of this is that parameter should be a value not type. So say I need declate `Me* phonyMe` and do `using TValue = decltype(std::declval<TGetter>()(phonyMe));`. Passing just a type `(Me*)` throw an error.

Comment: On the second thought, since argument is a pointer `nullptr` could be used instead of 'phony' pointer. `using TValue = decltype(std::declval<TGetter>()(nullptr));`

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`std::invoke_result`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/result_of) (since C++17).

```
using TValue = std::invoke_result_t<TGetter, Me*>;
```

Before C++17 you use [`std::result_of`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/result_of), note it's deprecated in C++17 and its usage is different with `std::invoke_result`.

```
using TValue = std::result_of_t<TGetter(Me*)>;
```

Comment: I saw that `invoke_result` but was reluctant to try it. We are currently on C++14 but slowly moving to C++17... Don't want to redone this later.

Comment: @user3124812 I added the usage of `std::result_of` as the workaround.

Answer (score 2):

If you only use `std::function`, you might do:

```
template <typename TGetter> class Handler;

template <typename Ret, typename ... Ts>
class Handler<Ret(Ts...)>
{
public:
    using TGetter = std::function<Ret(Ts...)>;

    Handler(TGetter getter) : m_getter(getter) {}

    using TValue = Ret;

private:
    TGetter                     m_getter;
    // ...

    bool handler();
};
```

with usage such as `Handler<std::string(Me*)> h(&getter);`

If you want any callable type, then:

```
template <typename TGetter>
class Handler
{
public:
    Handler(TGetter getter) : m_getter(getter) {}

    using TValue = decltype(declval<TGetter>()(/*args*/));

private:
    TGetter                     m_getter;
    // ...

    bool handler();
};
```